# Cannot change monitor refresh rate via VGA to DVI connector

Tags: xorg, xrandr, display-resolution, vga, dvi

I am using some old CRT monitor currently with Nvidia g210 graphics. I am dual booting Win8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

What bogus me, is I cannot get desired resolution with max refresh rate as I get on Windows + screen is more "blurry" than on Win. Monitor is connected to graphic card via VGA to DVI adapter.

What did I try?

Followed guide at: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

xrandr output is :

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1024x768_75 (0x282)  6.000MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1056 end 1152 total 1280 skew    0 clock   4.69KHz
        v: height   75 start   78 end   88 total   91           c
```

cvt:

```
~$ cvt 1024x768 85.00
# 1024x85 52.21 Hz (CVT) hsync: 5.27 kHz; pclk: 6.75 MHz
Modeline "1024x85_60.00"    6.75  1024 1056 1152 1280  85 88 98 101 -hsync +vsync
```

And when I try to add it, it gets error like this:

```
  X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

Does someone know how to fix it please? Thanks!